# R: replacing a % character in a string with \%

Tags: r

I have a string and am trying to replace % with \%:

```
text1 <-  as.character("Test %")
text2  <- gsub("%", "\%", text1)
text2
```

But I am getting an error:
Error: '\%' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\%"

I would be grateful on help on how can I get this to work.

Comment: Try `sub('[%]', '\\\\%', text1)`.  If you wrap it with `cat`, it will print only one `\`

Comment: @akrun No need for the character class around `%`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Thanks it should work without `[]`.  DIdn't try it.